# Предложение - пока не "Информированный", вопросы задавать нельзя :)

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Подумалось - почему бы не сделать так, что пока новичок не получил знак `Информированный`, для которого надо всего лишь прочесть обзорную страницу - не разрешать задавать вопросы?

Глядишь, меньше будет вопросов, которые сразу приходится закрывать...

P.S. А вообще - полное засилье [гуглопрограммистов](https://habr.com/ru/post/521104/)... Распишешь, что и как делать - нет, пока не выдашь полностью сдачепригодный для препода код - не отстанут. Бывает, просто `#include` не напишешь - тут же крики "ерунду написал, не компилируется!". Просто руки опускаются.

Если не научить срочно ИИ программировать - скоро программировать будет некому :(

Comment: Не буду оригинальным и скажу, что всем (ну как всем, людям "сверху") пофиг.

Comment: Задать вопрос можно даже без регистрации)

Comment: @vp_arth Ну и что это меняет в моем предложении?...

Comment: Будет просто меньше вопросов

Comment: @PashaPash "Лучше меньше, да лучше" (с) Ленин :-)

Comment: Бесполезная задумка, как я думаю. Если считаете, что кто-то будет считать, то сильно сомневаюсь в этом, а обучение во время создания вопроса уже и так есть

Comment: Администрации выгодно появление как можно большего количества вопросов каждый день для привлечения поискового трафика. Мусорные вопросы с этой задачей справляются на много лучше.

Comment: Не будет меньше, да лучше. Будет просто меньше :) Принудительная промотка тура никак не влияет на качество вопросов, это просто техническое препятствие в воронке "полный треш от сотни новичков" -> "пара нормальных задающих"

Comment: @PashaPash Пока что, судя по голосам, ваше мнение все еще не разделяется большинством...

Comment: ну вы прямо как наш ЦИК голоса считаете :) на ответе "за" пока больше минусов, чем плюсов :)

Comment: А какую проблему это решает? Разве наличие вопросов низкого качества кого то (кроме отвечающих) беспокоит? Если у сайта и есть какие то kpi, то там навряд ли есть что то про качество вопросов. Надо понимать, что привлечение новых юзеров и  новых вопросов любого качества для сайта важнее, чем удобства старожилов - старожилы уже здесь, старожилы и так уже отвечают на вопросы, так смысл делать нам удобней в ущерб потоку вопросов?

Comment: @PashaPash, простой способ избежать бездумного пролистывания – сделать мини-тест после прочтения и, пока тест не будет пройден, всё ещё не позволять задавать вопросы.

Comment: @tym32167 Интересно, когда ваш дом превращается в помойку с обоссанным лифтом и сломанной дверью в подъезд - вы тоже удивляетесь - разве это кого-то беспокоит, кроме жильцов? А они потерпят, местным забулдыгам отлить в лифте нужнее...

Comment: Мне как раз и приходилось участвовать в решении такой проблемы. И, в отличии от сайта, тогда жильцы что то могли решить. А здесь мы не дома, мы в гостях у владельцев SO и ничего нам важного решить не дадут. Сколько уже было примеров, что на русскоязычной части, что англоязычной. А еще у меня есть опыт работы с сообществами, и я видел, к чему приводит закручивание гаек для новобранцев. Чем больше шагов новенькому надо сделать, чтобы задать вопрос - тем меньше вопросов будет задаваться, что противоречит цели сайта. Потому я очень удивлюсь, если ваше предложение получит поддержку администрации.

Comment: @V-Mor и какой эффект будет от такого теста, при наличии других русскоязычных community, где нет никаких тестов и прочей "элитности" перед регистрацией? резкое падение количества вопросов. Зачем задавать вопрос на ruSO с тестов и прочим, если можно пойти на тостер и задать там без этого ритуала? ну ок, отфильтуете домашки, ценой 90% новичковых вопросов. получите 4 новичковых вопроса вместо 40 по тому же C#. Станет неинтересно (скучно), все уйдут. Это и есть цель? снизить количиество вопросов?

Answer (score 17):

Я бы предложил другое решение.

Что если вместо того, чтобы заставлять новичка что то читать, просто дать ему подсказки сразу при написании вопроса?
Например, у нас сейчас только 3 поля для ввода вопроса - заголовок, основная часть и метки.
А что если разбить основную часть на несколько полей?

1. Краткое описание проблемы
2. Шаги воспроизведения проблемы, текущий и ожидаемый результаты
3. Как вы сами пытались решить проблему? Что не получилось?

Пусть обязательным к заполнению будет только (1), зато тех, кто действительно что то пытался самостоятельно решить, не придется переспрашивать одни и те же вопросы.

А те, то ничего не читает и просит сделать домашку, также смогут продолжить постить вопросы низкого качества. То есть эффект на поток юзеров и вопросов должен быть минимальный.

Comment: 1. Не работает! 2. Что-то нажал, не пошло. 3. Помогите! - как-то так будет. Но идея хорошая, поддерживаю.

Comment: ну то есть хуже от этого не станет, но какой то процент вопросов станет лучше.

Comment: 3тий пункт мне очень нравится, поддерживаю

Comment: 3. За ранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

## Хорошая идея. Обеими руками за!

Единственный минус, достаточно просто страницу пролистать, но все-таки это повысит качество вопросов.

Comment: Но понизит количетсво вопросов и люди будут еще больше создавать новые вопросы в ответах. Тогда надо запрещать писать и ответы.

Comment: @SKIP А это снизит кол-во ответов. Лучшая идея: не давать репутации пока не прочитаешь ;)

Comment: Боюсь что от вас не зависит изменение даного функционала)))

Comment: @nick_n_a Я просто высказал свое мнение. При чем тут "не от тебя зависит" ?